# Format Time Widget ActiveForm yii2

Tags: php, time, yii2

Good afternoon I need to format the input of a time type field in the widget active form, my form should be short time without the seconds, the field is defined in the table of type time, is there any way to tell it to the widget actiform or model this field is of format "php: h: i".

Thank you very much,

Wilmer.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'turnos008')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control col-md-2 inicio']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering your field(In Controller for example), you can do like below:

*I assumed that the time is 12:20:21 AM*

```
//for example: output is : 12:20 AM
$model->turnos008=Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->turnos008, 'short');

//for example: output is : 12:20:21 AM
$model->turnos008=Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->turnos008, 'medium');

//for example: output is : 12:20:21 AM GMT
$model->turnos008=Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->turnos008, 'long');

//for example: output is : 12:20
$model->turnos008=Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->turnos008, 'php:h:i');
```

You may take a look at `Yii2`'s official document on http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asTime()-detail

Answer (score 0):

**Display In form:** format `"php: h: i"`

```
<?= $form->field($model,'fieldTime')->textInput(['value' => date('h:i', $model->fieldTime)]) ?>

<?php if (extension_loaded('intl')): ?>
   <?= $form->field($model,'fieldTime')->textInput(['value' => \Yii::t('user', '{0, date, hh:mm}', [$model->fieldTime])]) ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'fieldTime',['inputOptions' => ['value' => \Yii::$app->formatter->asTime($model->fieldTime, 'php:h:i')]]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'fieldTime')->textInput(['value' => \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->fieldTime, 'php:h:i')]) ?>
```

Note: Change 'fieldTime' as your field name

**Rull validation**: [Link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#date)

```
[
    [['from_date', 'to_date'], 'date'],
    [['from_datetime', 'to_datetime'], 'datetime'],
    [['some_time'], 'time'],
]
```